# Can "Login Access Policies" be applied to profiles other than the System Administrator?

Tags: user-management, custom-profile, grant-login-access

System administrator Profile users can have the privilege of logging in as any user in salesforce. Can the same be achieved for users of some other custom profiles?

Answer (score 1):

You can have other profile users enabled to login as other users, but you will need to enable "Modify All Data" permission to that profile. Please consider the impact of giving this permission to that profile. Those users will start seeing all data in your org regardless of who is the owner.

For more details and steps, you can have a look at the below link where it has been discussed the same thing:

[--Please check this link for more details.](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000wlyAAAQ)

Answer (score 1):

You can [delegate administrative duties](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&type=0), including login access, which allows you to specify that named users can log in as other users. This gives you the ability to grant which users can log in as others without giving them "the keys to the kingdom" (Modify All Data).